# Dataframe not updating after running through function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's a small snippet of a function I have created. I use another function Insert_row_ that I define elsewhere, which I know works correctly.

EDIT: I went ahead and just put the entire function in here.

The issue that I am having is that when I run my function, the dataframe that it returns just ends up being the same one that I used as input. Is there something I'm missing in order to update the dataframe? I thought I was assigning a new version of each with each iteration.

```html
def check_for_skipped_sensors_and_add_nans(dataframe):
    for i, item in dataframe['tag'].items():
        if item == 52630:
            a = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 2
            b = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 52630
            c = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 1
            if a == True:
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+2, dataframe, nan_row)
            if b == True:
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+2, dataframe, nan_row)
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+3, dataframe, nan_row)
            if c == True:
                pass
        if item == 1:
            a = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 52630
            b = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 1
            c = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 2
            if a == True:
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+2, dataframe, nan_row)
            if b == True:
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+2, dataframe, nan_row)
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+3, dataframe, nan_row)
            if c == True:
                pass
        if item == 2:
            a = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 1
            b = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 2
            c = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 52630
            if a == True:
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+2, dataframe, nan_row)
            if b == True:
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+2, dataframe, nan_row)
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+3, dataframe, nan_row)
            if c == True:
                pass
        if dataframe['tag'][i] == 'nan':
            pass
```

EDIT:

Here's the insert_row_ function:

```html
def Insert_row_(row_number, df, row_value): 
    # Slice the upper half of the dataframe 
    df1 = df[0:row_number] 
   
    # Store the result of lower half of the dataframe 
    df2 = df[row_number:] 
   
    # Inser the row in the upper half dataframe 
    df1.loc[row_number]=row_value 
   
    # Concat the two dataframes 
    df_result = pd.concat([df1, df2]) 
   
    # Reassign the index labels 
    df_result.index = [*range(df_result.shape[0])] 
   
    # Return the updated dataframe 
    return df_result
```

I unfortunately can't share any of the data. But the 'tag' column is essentially 52630,1,2,52630,1,2....etc repeating for 7000 rows.

Every once in a while it skips one of the values in the sequence, what I want to do is insert a row of nans when it does, which is what the Insert_row_ function successfully does.

Hopefully this provides more context!

Comment: what `Inser_row_` function return ?

Comment: probably that coondition does not work?  ```if dataframe['tag'][i] == 52630``` please add some of your data so we can help you. Part of ```insert row``` will also help us

Comment: Hi , I added the insert row function and provided some clarification on the data that I hope helps!

Comment: I think it would be more simple for you to filter out the data then manipulate it then add it back into an empty dataframe.  Readiblity is difficult with the existing approach.  Can you abstract an data sample that can be worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that your `Insert_row_` function works correctly, then my suspicion is that you are using `for i in dataframe['tag']` and thinking that i then indexes that column, but in reality, i is each element in that column. This could then throw off your comparisons in the next couple of lines and skip over the whole modification portion, etc.

In order to get the index, you could use the following:

```py
def check_for_skipped_sensors_and_add_nans(dataframe):
    for i, item in dataframe['tag'].items(): # gets (index, value) tuples
        if item == 52630:
            a = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 2
            b = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 52630
            c = dataframe['tag'][i+1] == 1
            if a == True:
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+2, dataframe, nan_row)
            if b == True:
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+2, dataframe, nan_row)
                dataframe = Insert_row_(i+3, dataframe, nan_row)
            if c == True:
                pass
    return dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks! So I tried that and it did end up changing the dataframe, but the dataframe I ended up with wasn't exactly what I wanted. I think there might be an issue with the rest of the code I wrote.